# Export frames of animation separately

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, png, animation

I'm working with lots of Photoshop animations provided to me by a designer. Each one is made of six frames, and I need to export each frame so that they have the titles (say): left*.png, where * is 0-5 depending on the frame.

Does anyone know if there's a quick way of doing this? So far I've been doing it by hand, but this is obviously far from ideal considering I have *many* animations to get through!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set each frame duration to 1 second. Then go to **File > Export > Video render**

Select **"Images sequence"**, **"All images"** and set the frequency to **1 image per second**.

Click on **Render**, and each frame should be exported to an image.

Comment: What kind of sorcery... I exported 200 layers in 20 seconds, whereas the more obvious path of Scripts > Export Layers to Files takes about 15 minutes.

Comment: Trust Adobe to put the export images under the export Video menu item. Also if you use an animation with alpha then you get an all black image, great work Adobe!

Comment: @malhal not sure if you figured it out by now, in the 'File Options' section you need to select 'Image Sequence' as **PNG** then in the 'Render Options' select alpha channel as **Straight - Unmatted**

Answer (score 5):

For people looking for exports with a transparent background..

First export all frames to layers:

**Timeline panel** > **Flatten Frames Into Layers**

[image: Flatten Frames Into Layers]

Then Export all layers to files:

**File** > **Export** > **Layers to files**

[image: Then Export all layers to files]